# Why can't I declare a trait function with tuple parameter matching?

Tags: syntax, rust, traits

Why is it that I cannot declare a trait function with tuple parameter matching?

```
#![allow(unused)]

// This works
fn foo((x, y): (i32, i32)) {
}

trait Bar {
    // This does not work
    fn bar((x, y): (i32, i32));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ce092e0146354cbbf09319117a706761&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Compiling the above outputs this:

```
error: expected one of `)` or `,`, found `:`
 --> src/main.rs:7:18
  |
7 |     fn bar((x, y): (i32, i32));
  |                  ^ expected one of `)` or `,` here

error: expected one of `!`, `&&`, `&`, `(`, `)`, `*`, `<`, `?`, `[`, `_`, `dyn`, `extern`, `fn`, `for`, `impl`, `unsafe`, or lifetime, found `:`
 --> src/main.rs:7:18
  |
7 |     fn bar((x, y): (i32, i32));
  |                  ^ expected one of 17 possible tokens here

error[E0601]: `main` function not found in crate `playground`
  |
  = note: consider adding a `main` function to `src/main.rs`
```

Comment: What does pattern matching accomplish in a trait definition? You can still have trait implementations use pattern matching there.

Comment: @PeterHall I think it provides better readability for the users of the trait

Comment: @PeterHall: You could also argue _what argument names accomplish in a trait definition?_. If an argument name in a trait function is best described as a tuple, I don't see why it should not be allowed.

Comment: Perhaps [log a feature request](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax is not supported in Rust, and there currently are no open RFCs to change that.

In a trait it would serve no purpose other than perhaps for documentation. But, since you are defining the trait anyway, you could just define a more descriptive type for that argument in the first place. In your case, a `Point` with `x` and `y` fields.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I do believe this should be a feature as it seems inconsistent with other function definitions.

Comment: This is a known issue and there is already a [request](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/1351#issuecomment-153070147) for this feature. Also, there's a more descriptive [error message](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/53046#issuecomment-410410601) which should have been emitted.

Comment: @algonomicon I think that is _slightly_ different. The main post is about forbidding trait method arguments without identifiers. The comment you linked to is pointing out the discrepancy between normal functions and default implementations of trait methods. Based on some of the other comments, it sounds like you'd get your wish if that was ever fixed because of keeping the parser simpler, and not needing to parse a method's arguments differently according to whether or not it has a default body.